# Zend Framework Deleting through a data mapper module.

Tags: zend-framework

I am still having problems getting table relationships defined, and have just changed the relationship between users and comment classes as advised, but when I went to test I got a new error.

```
C:\wamp\www\megashare\application\models\UsersMapper.php
public function deleteUser($id, Default_Model_Users $users){

        $usersTable = new Default_Model_DbTable_Users();        
        $usersRowset = $usersTable->find( $id );    
        $userToDelete = $usersRowset->current();            
        $userToDelete->delete();

    }
```

Generates the following error:

```
Zend Error Type: EXCEPTION_OTHER
REQUEST_URI: /megashare/public/users/delete/userId/14
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\wamp\www\megashare\application\models\UsersMapper.php(104): Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract->delete()
#1 C:\wamp\www\megashare\application\models\Users.php(761): Default_Model_UsersMapper->deleteUser(14, Object(Default_Model_Users))
#2 C:\wamp\www\megashare\application\controllers\UsersController.php(112): Default_Model_Users->deleteUser(14)
#3 C:\wamp\www\megashare\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(512): UsersController->deleteAction()
#4 C:\wamp\www\megashare\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(288): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('deleteAction')
#5 C:\wamp\www\megashare\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(936): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#6 C:\wamp\www\megashare\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(77): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#7 C:\wamp\www\megashare\library\Zend\Application.php(303): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#8 C:\wamp\www\megashare\public\index.php(31): Zend_Application->run()
#9 {main}
```

Comment: Voted down. Please edit your original question, or mark it as answered.

Comment: Also, fix your formatting before updating your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but this error has stopped now. There is nothing wrong with the code in this sample. There are other issues which are not related to this question. Therefore consider this question answered.    I think the underlying model class definitions must have been unworkable.